# When making 90-degree nested mullions what sort of jig keeps the router cuts perfectly aligned?

Tags: windows, routers

I need to replace the frame and sash of a wooden window and would like to paint it to match other windows (a feature that makes a purchased window rather expensive, since divided lites are usually faked nowadays) and so I am going to try to make it myself. I've never made a window.  When making the sort of  mullion that runs the entire height of the window between the rails, mating perpendicularly with another mullion that runs the entire width between the stiles, as in the photo, what kind of jig is used on the router table to make sure that parallel mullions have their cuts routed in exactly the same location?

[image: intersecting mullions]

Comment: Stops carefully positioned by precise measurement.

Comment: What if the mullion is longer than the router table? Is there such a thing as a "mullion sled" that slides perpendicular to the fence?

Comment: Does the router table have fittings to hold extension bars or brackets? This is not a "what if" blog.

Comment: @SolarMike:  The mullion's cut location could be further from the mullion's end than roughly half the length of fence.  I may need to upgrade the fence if stops are the way this is typically done and there are no special-purpose jigs or sleds.

Comment: You can index on the cut next to it, rather than the end. You can temporarily hot glue them all together and cut them all in one operation. You can beat your apprentice (in a local laws of the time compliant manner) and take the cost of the wasted wood out of their pitiful wages until they learn cut them all the same. You can tell your CNC router to make the cuts just so. There are many approaches.

Comment: Depending on your experience, it might be better to have a local woodworking shop do the cuts, they probably have nicer machines.  Jigs are nice to have to make cuts repeatable, but they also need to made well with some precision  to do a good job.  Making exact measurements is usually the hardest part of the job.